# How to do a unit test for Http Get without using http backend, I want to mock the backend instead, I'm using jasmine and Angular 1?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How to do a unit test for Http Get without using http backend, I want to mock the backend instead of doing a real call with http backend.

I'm using Jasmine, Karma runner with Angular version 1?

**This is my current code that works but using Http Backend:**

```
describe('appService', function() {
    beforeEach(module('msApp.services'));
    beforeEach(module('msApp.environment'));

    var scope, appServiceMock, httpBackendMock, environment;

    describe('service tests', function() {
        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $injector, Environment) {      
              scope = $rootScope.$new();    
              environment = Environment;

              //I want to mock the httpBackend bit here:
              httpBackendMock = $injector.get('$httpBackend');  
              appServiceMock = $injector.get('AppService');    
        }));

        afterEach(function() {
            httpBackendMock.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            httpBackendMock.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });          

        it('Test 1 - call login user', function() {  
            var user = {};

            spyOn(appServiceMock, 'loginUser');   

            appServiceMock.loginUser(user, jasmine.any(Function), jasmine.any(Function));

            expect(appServiceMock.loginUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(user, jasmine.any(Function), jasmine.any(Function));
        });

        it("Test 2 - call http directly", function(){
            var taskId = 1;

            httpBackendMock.expectGET(environment.apiURL + 'Tasks/GetTask?sessionId='+ scope.session + "&taskId=" + taskId)
            .respond(200, data);

            function mockSuccessFunction(){return true;};

            appServiceMock.getTask(taskId, mockSuccessFunction, jasmine.any(Function));                                  

            httpBackendMock.flush(); 
        })              
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't do a real call, you mocked it by telling it to respond with your data

Comment: Is that the correct way to do this type of unit test?

Answer (score 2):

I can't remember the details, but I did it a long time ago by using $httpBackend but telling it to pass the calls on to the actual internet like this:

`$httpBackend.whenGET(/regex/).passThrough();`

---update---

I just came across the code where I did it.  The details are here:
http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/16/unit-test-http-ngmock-passthrough/

Answer (score 0):

I used [angular-resource.js](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) in my app to mock out the backend.  You just need to add the ngResource module and call $resource("api/url/:id") for the endpoints which you want to mock out.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a mocked `$http` instead of getting actual injected service.

```
describe('appService', function() {
  beforeEach(module('msApp.services'));
  beforeEach(module('msApp.environment'));

  var $http, scope;

  describe('service tests', function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $provide) {      
          scope = $rootScope.$new();    
          $http = jasmine.createSpyObj('$http', ['get']);
          $provide.value('$http', $http);    
    }));
    it('get data', function() {
     $http.get();
     expect($http.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```